# Why is there no onchange for `<Input>` in Ant design

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, antd

I know I must be missing something very simple but why is there no `onChange` for `<Input>` tag of `Ant design`?

I would like the update the value of an input.

I assumed there was something like an `onChange`, since I was able to use `onChange` with `DatePicker` and `handleChange` `DropDown`; but I guess I assumed wrong

When I looked at the docs, there is a `onPressEnter` callback, but that is not really going to help me.

I tried the following:

```
   <Input
     placeholder="Flight name"
     size="large"
     value={this.state.someVal}
   />
```

But this just gave me an input that I could not type in.

So to reiterate:

1. Why is there no `onChange` for `<Input>` tag of `Ant design`?
2. More importantly, how do I get the value of the `<Input>` tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `onChange`, why not?

```
<Input
     placeholder="Flight name"
     size="large"
     value={this.state.someVal || ''}
     onChange={this.onChange}
   />
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({someVal: e.target.value})
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did not see onChange on the docs for `<Input>` and I did not know to put the `|| ''` to make the input actually accept what I was typing.  I knew it was something simple, but how I would have figured this out with out your help I don't know. :-) . Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar what if we are using Form and input of antd together, will this trick work ? there is something called 'onFinish' <Form onFinish={----}>

Comment: Form is for on submit.