# A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

^ This error is popping up when I'm pressing on Edit Button,

Any suggestions?

Code :

```
render() {
    const {isEditMode} = this.state;
    const {todoItem, submitEdit, deleteItem} = this.props;

    return <li>
        {
            isEditMode ? (
                <div>
                    <input
                        ref={this.inputRef}
                        defaultValue={todoItem.todo} type={'text'}
                    />
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            submitEdit(todoItem._id, this.inputRef.current.value);
                            this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode})
                        }}
                        className={'btn btn-primary'}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode})
                        }}
                        className={'btn btn-primary'}
                    >Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <input ref={this.btnRef} onClick={() => this.props.checkSingleCheckBox(todoItem._id)} type={'checkbox'} checked={todoItem.checked}/>
                    <label>
                        {todoItem.todo}
                    </label>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        deleteItem(todoItem._id)
                    } } className={'btn btn-primary'}>Delete
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.setState({isEditMode: !isEditMode})} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    </li>

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `defaultValue`:

```
value={todoItem.todo}
```

The `defaultValue` is used only for initial / constant value. Keeping this won't allow you to change the `value`. So, updating state on that reference element, you'll get such error: changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

> that way I'm unable to change the value of input field

You'll need to bind `onChange` event to trigger the changes for the input value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but that way I'm unable to change the value of input field,Is there any other way?

Comment: Let me know if updated answer helps or not. I'll provide further detail accordingly.

Comment: Okay I will try it

Comment: Its not changing the value still,and if I try to put defaultValue again or remove value at all it gives me same error

Comment: handleInputValue = (event) => {
  this.setState({input:event.target.value})
 }

Comment: <input
       ref={this.inputRef}
       type={'text'}
       value={todoItem.todo}
       onChange={(event) => this.handleInputValue(event)}
      />

Comment: The value is being tracked correctly and even label value is changing too but this damn error is till popping out

Comment: First of all, don't use defaultValue. Now, you're setting value with `todoItem.todo` so, you'll need to change that when onChange event occurs. If you're trying to change something else, it will not work.

Comment: See this if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378848/why-is-there-no-onchange-for-input-in-ant-design/52378880#52378880